# Error code -25308 (errSecInteractionNotAllowed) when accessing shared keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, keychain

I'm developing a react-native app using https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain to save and get things from keychain.

The things stored in keychain (and some other things) should be accessible from all our apps. So in xcode under capabilities I have activated an app-group "group.something.test".

I'm using setGenericPassword function of react-native-keychain like this:

```
await Keychain.setGenericPassword(
  'a username',
  'a password', 
  { 
    service: 'a userId', 
    accessible: Keychain.ACCESSIBLE.ALWAYS, 
    accessGroup: 'group.something.test', 
    accessControl: Keychain.ACCESS_CONTROL.DEVICE_PASSCODE
  }
);
```

In the native module this will store it to the keychain something like this:

```
SecAccessControlRef sacRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                 kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,
                                                                 kSecAccessControlDevicePasscode,
                                                                 &error);
NSDictionary *attributes = attributes = @{
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecClass: (__bridge id)(kSecClassGenericPassword),
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrService: service,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccount: username,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecValueData: [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessControl] = (__bridge id)sacRef,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessGroup] = accessGroup;
  };

...
    OSStatus osStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, NULL);
...
```

And keychain items are retrieved in the following way:

```
await Keychain.getGenericPassword({ service: 'a userId' });
```

Which will will run the following native code:

```
NSDictionary *query = @{
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecClass: (__bridge id)(kSecClassGenericPassword),
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrService: service,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecReturnAttributes: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecReturnData: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecMatchLimit: (__bridge NSString *)kSecMatchLimitOne,
    (__bridge NSString *)kSecUseOperationPrompt:@"Authenticate to retrieve secret"
  };

CFTypeRef foundTypeRef = NULL;
  OSStatus osStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) query, (CFTypeRef*)&foundTypeRef);
```

This works fine in the first app, I can store and retrieve an item from the keychain.
When I deploy a second app through xcode by just changing Display name and Bundle identifier to something different it also works. I can retrieve the key saved by the first app.
However if I now go back to the first app and try to retrieve the keychain item osStatus is -25308 (errSecInteractionNotAllowed).
If I uninstall the second app, it will start working in the first app again.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something more I need to do in the project settings?
I have also tried with keychain group capability, having the same keychain group as the first index in the keychain groups array, using that id as kSecAttrAccessGroup.